# Solving for inductance L in an AC series+parallel circuit is .. quartic?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductance

This seems like a painfully simple question, but I keep ending up having to solve a quartic equation. So I'm missing something obvious.

Let's say we have a an AC source feeding a load consisting of a series resistor, Rs, and then in parallel a resistor and an inductor, Rp  and L. I know the frequency of the AC source, and I know the series and parallel resistors Rs and Rp. I also know the voltage of the source, \$V_S\$, and the voltage at the divider between Rs and the parallel elements, call this \$V_L\$.

Here's where things go wonky.

I know that the magnitude of the impedance across the parallel elements because it is simply \$V_L \over V_S\$ divided across \$ R_p || L\$. However, when I try to solve the parallel equation for two complex numbers I end up with a horrific quartic expression for the magnitude of the impedence as a function of L.

Here's what I did:

(1) Start with the voltage divider:

\${V_L \over V_S} = { |Z_L| \over |Z_L|+R_s }\$

(2) Solve for \$|Z_L|\$:

\$ \alpha = {V_L \over V_S}, { |Z_L| } = { \alpha R_s \over { 1 - \alpha }} \$

(3) The right side is constant, so let's set up an expression for \$L\$:

\$ { Z_L } = { { R_p j \omega L } \over { R_p + j \omega L } } \$

(4) Since I want to know the magnitude of \$Z_L\$ I need to separate out \$Re\$ and \$Im\$, which means multiplying by the complex conjugate:

\$ { { R_p j \omega L } \over { R_p + j \omega L } } \cdot { { R_p - j \omega L } \over { R_p - j \omega L } } \rightarrow  {{ R_p (\omega L)^2 } \over { R_p^2 + (\omega L)^2}} + j {{ R_p^2 \omega L } \over { R_p^2 + (\omega L)^2}}  \$ ... !!!!

I succeed in creating two expressions for \$Re\$ and \$Im\$, and then solving for the \$ \sqrt { R_p^2 + X_L^2 } \$ is this when reducing to a function of \$L\$:

Let \$ |Z_L|=K \$, so that \$0=(\omega L)^4 (R^2 - K^2) - (\omega L)^2(2R^2K^2 + K^4) - K^2R^4 \$ ...

R, K & omega are all constants, but did I miss something obvious because solving a 4th order seems a bit ridiculous?

EDIT: Some more research and this form appears to be a [biquadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Biquadratic_equation) equation which is easy to solve. Still wasn't expecting to see this complexity solving for L.

SOLUTION: I forgot mag(a/b) = mag(a)/mag(b). Applying this to 3 yields a simple quadratic for f(L). Thanks @Barry below.

Comment: In (1), \$\frac{V_L}{V_S}=\frac{Z_L}{Z_L +R_S}\$. There may be other things wrong, I haven't gone any further.

Comment: If  you solve by removing Rp then swapping with L,  Does that make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know both the source voltage and the voltage across the divider network, you can ignore phase and just use the magnitudes of the voltages and impedances. The magnitude of the parallel combination of the L and R can be found from the expression you had by dividing the magnitude of the numerator by the magnitude of the denominator.  This will result in a much simplified expression than what you did.  Apply that expression in the voltage divider equation.  Multiply it out and place the term with the square root on one side and all the other terms on the other side.  If you then square both sides, you will wind up with a quadratic equation for L

Comment: Usually a 'math' explanation requires *actual* math to prove the concept you write about. Use Latex or other markup symbols to create the equations as an example for the OP to see. The OP did much work so going half way is ok to do.

Comment: @Barry Ah dangnabbit. I forgot mag(a/b) = mag(a)/mag(b). This is what happens when you try to do complex math 30+ years out of EE school. Lemme go down that path...

Comment: Yep. Way easier with that property. Thanks!